# React Native ListView not selectable after 10 items in list

Tags: listview, reactjs, react-native

I have created a list view with selectable rows but when the rows go beyond 10 the selection stops working.

Here it is with only 9 items added to the list:
[image]

```
// Individual row function
row(data, secId, rowId) {
  // place in queue
  let place = Number(rowId) + 1;

  // set the selected queuer to show its page
  let setSelectedQueuer = () => {
    this.setState({
      selectedKey: data._key,
      editName: data.name,
      editParty: data.partySize,
      editPhone: data.phoneNumber,
      editNotes: data.notes
    });
  }

  return (
    <Queuer
      key={data._key}
      queuerKey={data._key}
      place={place}
      name={data.name}
      selectedKey={this.state.selectedKey}
      createdAt={data.createdAt}
      partySize={data.partySize}
      onPress={setSelectedQueuer}
    />
  );
}
```

This sets each rows key when created and when clicked changes the state to then be compared on each row individual row item.

```
let isSelected = () => {
  if (this.props.queuerKey === this.props.selectedKey) {
    return Colors.info;
  } else {
    return 'white';
  }
}
```

Working great until a tenth item is added and it just stops.
[image]

Clicking on other row items but the style is not changing. Something weird is happening when the 10th item is added.

Comment: interesting more code please, and please move the following code out of row function it can decrease performance of your app.                                        "let setSelectedQueuer = () => {
    this.setState({
      selectedKey: data._key,
      editName: data.name,
      editParty: data.partySize,
      editPhone: data.phoneNumber,
      editNotes: data.notes
    });
  }
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it! I didn't set the `initialListSize` on my listview. `initialListSize` defaults to 10 and stops rerenders after that size has been reached.

This helped:
[React Native ListView doesn't rerender for large data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39720153/react-native-listview-doesnt-rerender-for-large-data?rq=1)